# Why are deleted questions still in the review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues

Why are deleted questions still in the review queue?

I recently flagged a question that, once I had finished the review task, was shown to me to be deleted two days ago.

This seems like a waste of effort.  Is there some automated process that scrubs deleted questions out of the review queues?

Comment: Are you sure that wasn't an audit, and you were not congratulated for not failing the "are-you breathing-test"?

Comment: Guess it was an audit.  I had never seen one, and couldn't find a question that explained why that task was there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10857863) was a review *audit*. Just a check to make sure you were awake. Shockingly, some people miss these.

#### See also: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)